# How to change a color of one letter in JTextField?

Tags: java, swing

I have a JTextField where I enter black characters.
I want the color of one letter in the text field to change to red under a certain condition. If this condition is not met, then the color changes back to black.

I tryed to use a `textField.setForegroung(new Color(237, 42, 42)`, but it changes a color of all text. I need to change a color of one character.

Comment: Not sure if `JTextField` can do this, but you'd have to make use of a `StyledDocument` to carry the individual styles of the characters

Answer (score 2):

You can't define the color of individual chars in a JTextField. You need to use a [JTextPane](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextPane.html) (or [JEditorPane](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JEditorPane.html)). With these components, you can use [DefaultStyledDocument](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/text/DefaultStyledDocument.html) to define your text styles.

Here's an example:

```
public class MyApplication extends JFrame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                MyApplication app = new MyApplication();
                app.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    private MyApplication() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(600, 600);

        StyleContext sc = new StyleContext();
        DefaultStyledDocument doc = new DefaultStyledDocument(sc);
        JTextPane textPane = new JTextPane(doc);
        textPane.setText("This is some colored text.");

        // Create a new style
        Style coloredCharStyle = sc.addStyle("ColorChars", null);
        coloredCharStyle.addAttribute(StyleConstants.Foreground, Color.red);

        // Define where the style should be applied
        doc.setCharacterAttributes(13,7,coloredCharStyle,false);

        // Add textPane to JFrame
        add(textPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        setVisible(true);
    }

}
```